# Exact Runge-Kutta coefficients

Tags: floating-point, precision, numerical-methods, floating-accuracy

When using numerical methods (e.g. [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods)), the finite precision of floats on the computer can influence the solution (Brouwer's Law).

In [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/634b/6cf565ffb265739750db74cc1d56169823bd.pdf) it suggests as a remedy simulating exact Runge-Kutta coefficients as e.g. A = B + C where B is an exact machine number, and C some small correction

Can someone explain how this works in practice? E.g. if A = 3/10, then how would one determine B and C?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paper they suggest using a rational approximation for A with denominator 1024.
(This means that A has at most 10 significant non-zero bits). You have (3/10)*1024 = 307.2, so B will be

B=307/1024 = 0.2998046875 and C = A - B = 0.0001953125

C is not exactly representable as IEEE Binary64, the nearest floating point number will be

C = 1.9531249999998889776975374843...E-4.

Insert these values in the formulas (3.1f)

Answer (score 1):

That trick may have worked in 2007 when the paper was submitted, but I think it would be unlikely to work on a modern platform.

On a modern x86 (both 32 and 64 bit) processor there are two separate instruction sets for floating point computations:

- the older x87 instructions (dating back to the original 8087 coprocessor), which had 80-bit registers
- more recent SSE instructions, which used registers of the same width as the format (32 bits for `float`, 64 bits for `double`).

The newer SSE instructions are generally preferred by modern compilers, as tend to be faster, as they can be fully pipelined, and support fancy things like SIMD operations. However in 2007, some compilers still only used x87 instructions by default, as the binaries could then be used on older machines (this was especially true on 32-bit machines).

The 80-bit registers supported a significand of up to 64-bits, which is 11-bits more than the 53-bit significand of a 64-bit `double`. The idea is that you could potentially reduce intermediate rounding error, which in this case you could exploit.

Consider a simpler version of their problem: computing

```
Y = A*X
```

by splitting `A` into `B+C` as they suggest, `B` has only 10 significant bits. Then the operation

```
B*X
```

does not incur any rounding error, since it will have at most 63 significant bits. The full computation

```
Y = B*X + C*X
```

will thus give you the result to almost the full 64 bits of accuracy.

Without the extended precision, `B*X` will generally incur rounding error of roughly the same size as if you had just compute `A*X` directly (unless `X` itself has been stored with reduce precision).

Now this sounds great: you might wonder why the SSE instructions got rid of this? Unfortunately, it wasn't predictable: in some cases the compiler would arrange it so that this would work, but in other cases it would need to "spill" the registers to memory, in which case you would lose this extra precision. This would in turn give sometimes bizarre results, like having operations such as `x+y == x+y` evaluate to false, depending on when the individual operations were evaluated.

However, all is not lost! If you have a fairly recent machine, you may be able to take advantage of [fused multiply-add (fma)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) operations to get increased accuracy. In this case, it would look something like

```
Y = fma(B,X,C*X)
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I do not see where the technique from the paper linked in the question relies on the presence of extended-precision hardware? It uses  (equation 3.1) separate accumulation using the high-order and the low-order parts of the coefficients, respectively, and combines the accumulated sums at the end. I agree that the existence of FMA now provides improved methods of compensated computations such as this one.

Comment: I've added a section on it: basically you need extended precision (or truncate the precision of `X`) to ensure that `B*X` can be computed without error. Otherwise, you will incur roughly the same size error as you would by computing `A*X` directly.

Comment: You are absolute right: we want the high-order products to be fully accurate before they are added to the sum and this requires extra bits. Not sure how I overlooked that ...